# conteúdo responsivo com barra lateral tamanho fixo

Tags: css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

É possível fazer um layout com conteúdo de lagura flexível e uma barra lateral de tamanho fixo?
Exemplo

```
    <body>
      <header></header>
       <article></article>
       <aside></aside>
    </body>
```

Eu quero deixar body com largura de 100%, aside sempre com 300px e article deveria assumir a diferença independente do tamanho/resolução de quem estiver acessando. E de preferencia apenas com css, sem javascript.

Ps. caso relevante, estou considerando este exemplo, mas queria deixar a barra de tamanho fixo
http://wpmidia.com.br/desenvolvimento-web/design-responsivo-em-3-passos/

Desde já agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso, é no seu exemplo, invertendo as ordem dos elementos `article` e `aside`.

Ao `aside` que no código é escrito antes do `article`, atribui-se um `float: right`, e dá-se a largura desejada. Já ao `article` atribui-se um `width: 100%` e um `margin` que pode ser igual ou maior ao `width` do `aside`. Assim, um tem uma largura fixa a outra ocupa o restante da tela.

### Exemplo

```css
   aside {
 float: right;
 width: 300px;
 background: blue;
 height: 100px;
}

article {
 margin-right: 300px;
 background: gray;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  Aside
</aside>
<article>
  Article
</article>
```

### [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7ru7qhb/1/)

Answer (score 2):

article { with: calc(100% - 300px); position: relative; }

aside { width: 300px; height: 100%;  position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }

Caso queira por o aside do lado direito eh trocar o left por right: 0.